# Windows 7 files won't unlock sometimes on Samba file server

Tags: windows-7, samba

We're running Windows XP and Windows 7 desktops on our network, with a Debian Squeeze file server running Samba 3.5.6. Our Windows 7 desktops are having problems opening MS Office docs at times, getting an error that the file is open by 'another user' even though no other user has it open.

It seems like the Windows 7 computers are failing to unlock files when they're closed. I've restarted samba, rebooted the server and still have the same issues. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There are several hotfixes for known File Sharing/SMB issues with Windows 7/2008/R2:

**List of currently available hotfixes for the File Services technologies**
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2473205

You are looking for the MRXSMB and RDBSS components (client).